# Creating Requirements

Tags: c#

My problem is simply that I am creating a small 2D game in C#. This game represents a character that has to kill monsters and gain Experience to increase his level.  As his level increases he will be able to wear higher level items as well as his strength points increase he will be able to unlock new items.

How could I restrict some items for specific levels and specific strengths by creating an Item requirements?  In the simplest yet powerful way so I don't want to have to involve a large ugly `SWITCH` or `IF ELSE` statement.

Note: You can imagine my question as an MMORPG game in which you drop items of different levels and types but only you are able to wear the items that suits your type and level. So simply I want someone to explain me that mechanism and how could I achieve it in C# in a professional way.

Comment: Create a method CheckRequirements(Character c) in your Item class. Implement it however you want (with ifs, with math, with a matrix of requirement, whatever), it probably won't be difficult. I don't really get the point of the question. Switch and if/else are not "ugly" in any way, and do the job they are crafted to do : check conditions.

Comment: @C4stor : But imagine a huge game that involves a lot of items and types. Do they create a very huge `switch` of `if else` codes in order to satisfy the all requirements their game needs ?

Comment: To all down voters I am just asking this question to learn more about C#. Also what involved me in that game creation is only that I want to increase my knowledge in c# so please stop down voting and try to help me out.

Comment: @ErricJManderin - Don't get upset about downvotes.  It's not a reflection upon you personally.  It is one of the tools provided by this site to help provide the most useful content to future visitors of the site.

Comment: @Erric J Manderin : this a QA website, not somewhere to learn. Q&A have to be precise in order to be useful and validatable. There is no "Answer" to your question, merely suggestions, which you can rank subjectively. The truth is, depending of your use case, you use different techniques. It's why I downvoted the question, because it's not "answerable", and not reusable as is by future users. This said, I hope you find something good for your case in the answers :)

Comment: @C4stor : look @ Daniel Hilgarth's Answer...

Comment: @C4stor : I see. It's good for some situations, not for others. Glad it's good for you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to utilize the [Specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

So, basically, your item would have a `WearerSpecification` property which returns a specification that returns true if the current character satisfies it.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class Item
{
    private readonly ISpecification<Character> _wearerSpecification;

    protected Item(ISpecification<Character> wearerSpecification)
    {
        _wearerSpecification = wearerSpecification;
    }

    public ISpecification<Character> WearerSpecification
    {
        get { return _wearerSpecification; }
    }
}
```

In the method that is called when the character tries to pick up an item, the code would look something like this:

```
public class Character
{
    public void PickUpItem(Item item)
    {
        if(item.WearerSpecification.SatisfiedBy(this))
        {
            // item can be picked up
        }
        else
        {
            // item can't be picked up
        }
    }
}
```

---

To simplify the actual creation of your items and to not repeat your code, you can create concrete specification classes that represent requirements that often occur, e.g. you could create a `AtLeastLevel10Specification` or a `MinimumStrengthSpecification`:

```
public class AtLeastLevel10Specification : ISpecification<Character>
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Character character)
    {
        return character.Level >= 10;
    }
}

public class MinimumStrengthSpecification : ISpecification<Character>
{
    private readonly int _minimumRequiredStrength;

    public MinimumStrengthSpecification(int minimumRequiredStrength)
    {
        _minimumRequiredStrength = minimumRequiredStrength;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Character character)
    {
        return character.Strength >= _minimumRequiredStrength;
    }
}
```

You would then possible use these classes directly inside your item declaration:

```
public class VeryHeavyShield : Item
{
    public VeryHeavyShield()
        : base(CreateSpecification())
    {
    }

    private static ISpecification<Character> CreateSpecification()
    {
        return new AtLeastLevel10Specification().And(
                   new MinimumStrengthSpecification(50));
    }
}
```

Comment: So is that considered a good approach ?. Also can you provide me with more ways that can achieve what I am asking for so that I can learn more ?. I will be very thankful for you though.

Comment: @ErricJManderin - If your goal is to learn, then the best advice to you would be: stop trying to get everything perfect in your head, and just start coding.  You'll learn from your mistakes, and you will also be able to ask better questions once you have code.

Comment: @ErricJManderin: I wouldn't have posted it, if it weren't a good approach. That's the approach I would use in one form or another.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth : I really appreciate your very valuable help Daniel and thank you very much.

Comment: @ErricJManderin: You are welcome. Please be sure to read the update, as it shows the biggest advantage over the simpler method provided by Rotem: the possibility to easily reuse and combine specifications.

Answer (score 3):

While Daniel's answer is sound and ultimately more versatile, I think simply implementing a method might be easier to comprehend for a c# beginner.
It's definitely better than a huge `switch` clause.

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual bool IsWearable(Character c)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class BananaSword : Item
{
    public override bool IsWearable(Character c)
    {
         return c.Level >= 10 && c.Race == CharacterRace.BananaWarrior;
    }
}

public class BananaDude : Character
{
    public List<Item> GetWearableItems()
    {
        return AllGameItems.Where(i => i.IsWearable(this)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note: This is an implementation of a simplified version of the Specification pattern I showed, basically implemented directly in the item class. However, it has the disadvantage that the specifications no longer can be combined or reused as is the case with the full implementation of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a "requirement"-array where you pack all your stats. The same array for each item and then iterate through them and set a boolean-false if the stat is to low.

Through this you basically would only have a a>=b check for each value.